# Achieve interstitialSection of Srolllify

Tags: jquery-scrollify

In this [Scrollify Demo](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#options) content height is greater than section height generated by default. Each Section has different height. Same scenario is with my code. I have a section with large amount of content. I have put this content class in interstitialSection. But that section is not behaving like demo.

```
<section class="features panel1 job-section">
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-x-s-12">
        <h1 class="career-color">Career Opportunities at TSR Darashaw</h1>
        <p class="career-desc">Be a part of TSRDL Family and embark upon the path of Growth, Excellence and Success. We strive to create a cohesive Family of competent team-mates inspired to serve our prestigious clientele.</p>
        <h3 class="career-color current-title">Current Openings</h3>
        <div CLASS="job">
            <h4 class="career-color">Associate - Payroll</h4>
            <ul class="job-details">
                <li><span>EXPERIENCE: </span><span>2-5 years</span></li>
                <li><span>Location:</span><span>Mumbai - Mahalakshmi</span></li>
                <li><span>JOB CODE:</span><span>AP001</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                      <p class="show-details">SHOW DETAILS</p> <button class="apply"><a href="#">APPLY NOW</a></button>
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <h4 class="career-color job-desc-title">JOB DESCRIPTION</h4>
                    <ul class="faq-points">
                        <li><span></span><p>Validity of the executed instrument of transfer</p>
                            <ul class="sub-points">
                                <li><span></span><p>for shares :- 60 days from the date of execution</p></li>
                                <li><span></span><p>for debentures :- for an indefinite period</p></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span></span><p>SEBI has notified vide its Circular No. MRD/DoP/Cir-05/2009 dated 20th May,2009 that it is mandatory for all transactions in the securities market including transfer of shares in physical form of listed Companies to be accompanied with copies of PAN Cards of ALL the transferees.</p></li>
                        <li><span></span><p>Further as per SEBI (Listing Obligations And Disclosure Requirements) Regulations 2015, both transferor and transferee are to furnish copy of PAN for transfer of securities.</p></li>
                        <li><span></span><p>Please therefore attach self attested copies of PAN Cards of both the transferee(s) and transferor(s) alongwith the instrument of transfer</p></li>
                        <li><span></span><p>Keep photocopies of certificates, instrument of transfer and other documents sent by post to TSRDL. In case of a loss in transit, they come in handy.</p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4 class="career-color job-desc-title">Profile requirements</h4>
                  <ul class="faq-points">
                      <li><span></span><p>Validity of the executed instrument of transfer</p>
                          <ul class="sub-points">
                              <li><span></span><p>for shares :- 60 days from the date of execution</p></li>
                              <li><span></span><p>for debentures :- for an indefinite period</p></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><span></span><p>SEBI has notified vide its Circular No. MRD/DoP/Cir-05/2009 dated 20th May,2009 that it is mandatory for all transactions in the securities market including transfer of shares in physical form of listed Companies to be accompanied with copies of PAN Cards of ALL the transferees.</p></li>
                      <li><span></span><p>Further as per SEBI (Listing Obligations And Disclosure Requirements) Regulations 2015, both transferor and transferee are to furnish copy of PAN for transfer of securities.</p></li>
                      <li><span></span><p>Please therefore attach self attested copies of PAN Cards of both the transferee(s) and transferor(s) alongwith the instrument of transfer</p></li>
                      <li><span></span><p>Keep photocopies of certificates, instrument of transfer and other documents sent by post to TSRDL. In case of a loss in transit, they come in handy.</p></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(function() {
    $.scrollify({
        section:".panel1",
        scrollSpeed:1100,
        interstitialSection : ".job-section",
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        overflowScroll: true,
        scrollbars: true,
        touchScroll:true,
        updateHash: false,
        offset : 0
    });
});
```

});

Scroll in demo is smooth for option section till next section. But whenever i have scrolled in my code, control goes directly to the next section.

How can i achieve this same as demo.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `job-section` class from your section.

Comment: I have removed the .job-section class from section but now section acquire the height: 770px which is less than content. also i can not see the content. When i scroll, cvontrol goes to next section.

Comment: It sounds like you have some collapsed content in your section, you must ensure that there is no collapsed content within your sections. This often happens when you have floated content within a container that isn't cleared. All content must be properly contained in order for an accurate section height to be calculated.

Comment: I have given overflow: hidden to section element. and none of element give float property. I have placed all the content properly in container.

Comment: Try temporarily removing all CSS and see if the section is still set shorter than the content.

Comment: I have used multiple bootstrap accordion in section. Whenever i refresh the page, section height shows 937px. but when i open multiples accordion, height is not getting update. due to this i can not select the bottom accordion.

Comment: You will need to call '$.scrollify.update()' when the accordion is opened. That will tell Scrollify to recalculate the section heights

Comment: I have called '$.scrollify.update()' function onaccordion opened. but section is flickering. goes slightly top and then revert back to its position. Also after opened the multiple accordion, smooth should be smooth till end of that section. and then next section should be open.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would occur. I'd suggest stripping your code down and building it up again to isolate the cause of the problem.

Comment: `afterRender:function() {
 jQuery('.srt-faq .panel-title a').click(function(){
  jQuery.scrollify.update();
 });
}`

I have written this way. Is this right way.

Comment: No, there wouldn't be any need to update Scrollify after render.

Comment: call it when the content is changed. Like when the accordion is opened...

Comment: I have called when the content is changed, but still it flickering.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would occur. I'd suggest stripping your code down and building it up again to isolate the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have created newly html code. In that i have kept a section with multiple accordion. As you have said, call update() on accordion open and close. but whenever i click, section is flickering. Also at bottom, footer does not seen completely. it scrolls upto half height of footer.

Comment: I have created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L38pxfps/) for your reference. Go at bootom accordion section. when you click on accordion heading, scrollify will update and flickering.

Comment: I'm not seeing flickering, which browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome...yes its goes slightly top and then come back to its original position. try to keep the result window at full width.

Comment: Are you seeing the same issues in this example? https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/examples/dynamic-content/

Comment: Yes. I am seeing the same issues. I have also recorded this issue. how can i share with you.

Comment: Are you able to host it somewhere? Maybe convert it to a gif and put it on imgur